# In C++, Can I change the argument type of a member function with changing the class declaration?

Tags: c++

Is this possible? So the change of this member function will be invisible from outside.
I guess probably not, while I want to make sure. Thanks!

add info:

```
class foo{
    private:
        A ();
        B (int b);
}

foo::A(){
    int b;
    B (b);
}

foo::B(int b){
    return (b > 1);
}
```

Now I want to change implementation of B() into:

```
foo::B(float b){
    return (b > 1.0);
}
```

Is there anyway I can keep the declaration of class foo unchanged, and when
doing

```
foo foo1;
foo1.A()
```

will work fine?

Comment: You [already asked this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084506), **verbatim**.  It was closed as *"**put on hold** as unclear...Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking."*

Comment: `A();` and `B (int b);` are illegal here. If they are meant to be function declarations they need a return type.

Comment: You do know that you can *overload* functions in C++, so that you can have two functions with the same name, but with different arguments, and the compiler will pick the right function to call depending on the arguments you pass? Besides, if you change the `B` function declaration to take a floating point argument instead of integer, the compiler will convert the integer argument you pass in `A` to a floating point.

Comment: Maybe you want to use a template parameter?

Comment: I apologize that I am pretty new to C++. So the point here is, if "float" is some new type that is defined by the one who coded class foo; then is it possible for some other one to call foo1.A(), without aware of this new type "float"?

Comment: Being "new to C++" is no excuse for such obviously poor behaviour as verbatim reposting a previously rejected question. Did you not consider following the advice you were given at the time?

Comment: My previous question was put "on hold" for lack of details. Then I added more info, and the status was still "on hold". Then I learned that this question was on the "review queue" for reopen. Then I did not want to wait in this queue. Then I deleted the previous question, and re-asked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway I can keep the declaration of class foo unchanged

No.  You must update the declaration of `foo::B()` to match its new implementation.

Also, your code will not compile as shown anyway, because `A()` is not public, and neither `A()` nor `B()` have return values defines.

Try this instead:

foo.h

```
class foo{
    public:
        void A ();
    private:
        bool B (float b);
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo::A(){
    int b;
    B (b);
}

bool foo::B(float b){
    return (b > 1.0);
}
```

If you want to hide `B()` from the outside world, don't declare it as a member of `foo` to begin with, in fact don't even declare it in `foo`'s header file at all:

foo.h

```
class foo{
    public:
        void A ();
};
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

static bool B(float b){
    return (b > 1.0);
}

void foo::A(){
    float b;
    B (b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is my understanding correct: making B() static public, outside class foo?

Comment: I was making it a standalone function within the same implementation file as `foo::A()` so it is unknown to the rest of the world, only used for `A()`'s implementation.

Comment: I would prefer the solution you suggested. The reason I asked the question here, was because someone commented this solution as sort of "c-style" solution, and he believed there was some sort of "c++ style" solution. I am not quite familiar with C++, his comment just rose my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the definition *must* match the declaration, so changing just the signature (name, return type, argument types) of the definition (implementation) but not the declaration will give you a compiler error.

However, like I said in my comment, you can change the argument type to a `float` and it will still work in most cases (depending on the range of values you pass to the function). And you could also add an overloaded function, if you want to be able to do different things depending on if you pass an `int` or a `float`.

There's also the possibility to use *templates*.